# I can't install skype in fedora 20-64bit

Tags: linux, installation, fedora, skype

I am newbiew in the world of Linux. I have `fedora 20 (64 bit)` installed in my system. I am trying to install skype in my system. However it throws an error

```
/opt/skype/skype: error while loading shared libraries: libXv.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The error says I am missing a file `libXv.so.1` in my installation. So I googled it and found out a solution for it. In most results, it says I need to run the following command

```
sudo apt-get install libxss1:i386 libqtcore4:i386 libqt4-dbus:i386
```

I dont have `apt-get` command. So I installed `apt` package in my system successfully and run the above command. But it gave me following error.

```
Reading Package Lists... Error!
E: opening /var/lib/apt/lists/download.fedoraproject.org_pub_fedora_linux_development_rawhide_x86%5f64_os_repodata_84cafdb58c1256eb6abcc0d6793f552b46300c46f747e9b0a5df9db392b23c44-primary.sqlite.xz db failed
E: Unsupported database scheme (0)
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

I get stucked here. What should I do now ? How can I succefully install this package and make my skype work.

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`apt-get` is for Ubuntu and other Debian-derived linuxes. For Fedora, use `yum`:

```
yum install libXv
```

Comment: I have used yum before apt-get. At that time it didn't work. But after this answer, I tried once more. Now I got that package. But skype again throws another file missing error again. So I am now doing this operation recursively now. I will let you know the result

Comment: You don't mention how you installed skype, but a good way to do that when you download the rpm from the skype website, is to do it with yum: `yum localinstall skype-4.3.0.37-fedora.i586.rpm`  This way, yum should help install needed dependencies like libXv.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still running Fedora 20, have you tried: clean yum cache and install forcing to replace the packages?

```
su -c 'yum clean packages' (also you can run: sudo yum clean all)
sudo yum install libXv --replacepkgs
```

For Fedora 24, [download Skype](http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-computer/). In my case it was version: skype-4.3.0.37-fedora.i586.rpm

Open terminal, go to ~/Downloads and run:

```
sudo dnf install skype-4.3.0.37-fedora.i586.rpm
```

That is it!